# how to limit the reorder in draglinearlayout (need some idea!)

Tags: java, android, github

i want to use draglinearlayout to do drag and drop action. See the link in Github https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout 
This source library allow user to drag those view added by the AddDragView(View,(View) findViewById(R.id.controller)).

In my draglinearlayout, i have various views (cannot drag) and many dragView. i want to limit the drag action across the normal view(cannot be drag). That mean if i try to drag the dragView across those normal view, it should detect it and stop my action.

Do I need to override which part of the source codes??
I have search for google using keyword 'draglinearlayout', but there are only few of relevant website and i cannot found what i want!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to remove your elements non-draggable from the DragLinearLayout and put it in a separate LinearLayout. I honestly don't think it is possible otherwhise.

Also you can't override some parts of the code ( like the ontouch events ) otherwhise it will cancel the draglinearlayout effect.

If you can't find what you want you can also open a new issue on the related github.

Comment: thank you for you answer, as i mention , the number of my normal view is various, so the number cannot be fixed and create a separate draglinearlayout for each non-drag view.

Comment: Is it possible for one of your non-draggable view to be between two draggable views for exemple?

Comment: yes, for example , a layout of 20 Views, the normal view are in 1,5,9,10,15,20(may vary next time). i want to limit the movement of dragView across those normal views.

Comment: so can a draggable view at the pos 10 be dragged to the 12 if the 11 is not draggable? if yes, those two ones exchange their position right?

Comment: no, i want to prohibit any drag across the non draggable view. In your case, i want to stop it once i know it try to drag across the normal view (11).   //By the way, the exchange position of draggable view is now work in this library. But that not i seek for.

Comment: ok so in this case, you have to add your elements dynamically. What I recommend you to do is to have one LinearLayout for everything. Lets imagine you have 7 elements: 1 2 4 5 draggables, 3  6 7 not. then start by adding in this linearlayout a draglinearlayout for 1 and 2. your next element 3 is different so create a linear layout on this one. the next element 4 is draggable so create, still programmatically, a draglinearlayout and keep using this one until you meet a non draggable element ( in this case, 6 ), and so on. I don't see any other solutions.

Comment: I m probably not clear since english is not my native language, What I want to mean is you have to loop on your elements and for every "set" of draggable elements following each others, create draglinearlayout to contain them.

Comment: ok, your idea! is good, but how to add this numbers of draglinearlayout dynamically , where should i put these element in which android component since it's height vary time by time.

Comment: Put the dynamic draglinearlayout in a parent LinearLayout you can create as a container for those draglinearlayout and your non draggable elements. The height shouldnt be a problem using this lib, and if you really need to change it, you can also set the params of the layout you create dynamically. You can find many tutorials to achieve that ( like this one:http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html) . You can achive that wiithout having to touch your xml file this way.

Answer (score 0):

Because of addDragView(...) is actually addView(...) followed by setViewDraggable(...)

Try to use

```
layout.addView(view);
layout.setViewDraggable(view, view); // only if you want it dragable
```

instead of

```
layout.addDragView(imageView, imageView);
```